# How to tell if there's a render error when manually rendering a Django template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm using the Django template system for some form emails, with the templates editable by the end user.

A template's `render` method returns the rendered content and silently passes over invalid variables and tags. Is there a reasonable way to tell if there was an error during rendering?

I've considering setting `settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` to a unique string and then testing for the presence of this string but that would affect normal template rendering, which isn't acceptable. I've scanned Django's source code in the hope there is a "render invalid variable/tag" method I can override cleanly to raise an exception, but no such luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly enough hacking around the problem like that is the best solution available. It should be noted that the variable is called `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` btw.

Alternatively I would recommend using Jinja2 together with Coffin, that makes debugging a lot easier as well and Jinja2 actually does give proper stacktraces for errors like these.

Comment: Thanks for the spellcheck -- corrected. By hacking around, you mean...?

Comment: I mean that using your proposed method is currently the best and practically the only solution when using the Django template system.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could write the templates in [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) instead. It's a bit more powerful than Django's templating language, but can throw exceptions on non-existent variables - and the syntax is very similar.

It also provides similar `render` etc functions to do just what you're asking, without affecting any of the rest of your Django project.

For example:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Environment, StrictUndefined
>>> env = Environment(undefined=StrictUndefined)
>>> template = env.from_string('Say hello to {{name}}')
>>> 
>>> template.render()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
     return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'name' is undefined
>>>
>>> template.render({'name': 'Ben'})
u'Say hello to Ben'
>>>
>>> template.render(name='Ben')
u'Say hello to Ben'
```